# Subset Sum : Why is DFS + pruning faster than 2 for loop?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, recursion, time-complexity

This issue is leetcode 416 Partition Equal Subset Sum.

```
#2 for loop, which got TLE
class Solution(object):
    def canPartition(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: bool
        """
        nums.sort()
        allsum = sum(nums)
        if allsum % 2 == 1:
            return False
        subsets = {() : 0}
        temp = dict(subsets)
        for each in nums:
            for subset in subsets:
                new = temp[subset] + each
                if new * 2 == allsum:
                    return True
                elif new * 2 < allsum:
                    temp[tuple(list(subset) + [each])] = new
                else:
                    del temp[subset]
            subsets = dict(temp)
        return False

DFS + pruning:
class Solution(object):
    def canPartition(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: bool
        """
        nums.sort()
        if sum(nums) % 2 != 0:
            return False
        else:
            target = sum(nums) / 2
        return self.path(nums, len(nums), target)

def path(self, nums, length, target):#DFS + pruning
    if target == 0:
        return True
    elif target < 0 or (target > 0 and length == 0):
        return False
    if self.path(nums, length - 1, target - nums[length - 1]):
        return True
    return self.path(nums, length - 1, target)
```

Why is 2 for loop slower than DFS? They both have pruning, and I think the time complexity of DFS, which is a np problem, should be worse than 2 for loop, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you are using two loops it doesn't mean that your algorithm is in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* or polynomial. The complexity of the algorithm depends on how many times each loop executes.
In this part of code:

```
    for each in nums:
        for subset in subsets:
            ....
```

The first loop will run *n* times because the size of `nums` is *n* and it doesn't change. However size of `subsets` is getting 2 times larger after each iteration. So the body of your second `for` loop will executes `1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + ... + 2^n = 2^(n+1)` times.

So your algorithm is in *O(2<sup>n</sup>)* without even considering the costly operations (copying `list`s and `dict`s) you perform in the body of the second loop.

Your second method (Which is not technically a DFS) is equivalent to your first method in the case complexity. They both are *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. But in the second method you do less extra work in comparison to your first method (copying `list`s and `dict`s, etc). So your first method will might run faster but it doesn't matter in the long run. Both of this methods won't be efficient enough for a bigger size of input.

Note that this is a very famous problem called [Subset-sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) which is NP-Complete. It can be solved using [Dynamic Programming](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/) in [Pseudo-polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time).

Comment: Could you please tell me if my secod solution isn't a DFS based on recursion, what is it? I don't think it is backtracking, and I think it is just a search by traversal. Am I right? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You can call it DFS or you can call it Backtrack but usually we use the term DFS when there is an explicit graph, in this problem the graph is implicit.

Comment: Yes! As far as I know, Backtrack is just the DFS on an implicit graph! However, my algorithm doesn't have the process of jump back to an anterior state and resume moving forward along another branch, which is the core process of Backtrack( Isn't it ?). So could you please tell me, according to your point, what is the core conception of Backtrack? I'll read many explanation of Backtrack, while they are vague. Thank you very much! :D

Comment: Read the first paragraph of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). Your code tries to first use an item to reach the goal but when it sees that it can't reach the goal, it goes back and tries to reach the goal without using that item. I don't see why you can't see the backtracking in this.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I've acquired a deeper understanding of backtracking!